# Vagrant access denied: launch error after windows update

Tags: powershell, window, vagrant, virtualbox

I can't run any more my [vagrant virtual machine](https://github.com/zepgram/magento2-fast-vm) on the command line under Windows Powershell since a big Windows update.

I always get the following error:

```
> vagrant up
==> All dependencies are satisfied
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:158:in 'rescue in execute': Zugriff verweigert (5) (Vagrant::Util::Subprocess::LaunchError)
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:151:in `execute'

from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:22:in `execute'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/util/powershell.rb:115:in `execute_cmd'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:82:in `block in windows_admin?'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:84:in `windows_admin?'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/plugins/providers/hyperv/provider.rb:20:in `usable?'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:361:in `block in default_provider'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:49:in `block in each'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:48:in `each'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:48:in `each'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:347:in `default_provider'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:943:in `guess_provider'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:955:in `find_configured_plugins'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:983:in `process_configured_plugins'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:178:in `initialize'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/bin/vagrant:145:in `new'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/bin/vagrant:145:in `<main>'
```

Here is my setup:

Windows 10 Pro
Vagrant 2.2.7
Virtual Box 6.0.16

I also tried to launch run vagrant on Powershell administrator and Git bash too but I still got the same error.

Could you help me solve this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are missing some privileges to run vagrant,

try to check if you can run it from a cmd opened as administrator

Comment: thanks for the tip. Vagrant has run but I still got the same error at the end of the script launch.
I will also ask the developer of the virtual machine if he has any ideas about it.